# ASP.NET when Country is selected it loads dropdown with States if USA or Canada

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Please help,don't know what else to try.

I have a bug that I need to fix. Using user control NameAddress.ascx that has dropdown ddlCountry, depend on the coutry it loads user control StateProvince and put data in ddlState. It supposed to hide user control State if Country is not CA or US. Page is refreshed and I see in debug that lblState.Visible = false. Screen is not updated. If I choose Canada it loads the correct province. for Canada, but it still show the US states.
Also, usercontrol is using AJAX tool kit

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhStateProvince" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Text="State" />*<br />
    <uc:StateProvince ID="ucState" runat="server" 
                    CssClass="textinput" style="width: 45px;"  />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Comment: <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhStateProvince" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Text="State" />*<br />
              
                    <uc:StateProvince ID="ucState" runat="server" CssClass="textinput" style="width: 45px;"  />

                </asp:PlaceHolder>

Comment: please post some code, this is not enough to help you.